# Python GCSE - Using Lists

Tags: python, computer-science

In the next few weeks, I will be doing a computer science GCSE. I really need this GCSE as I aspire to because an Application Developer, so any help would be amazing! For the coding part of my GCSE, I need to create a python script that allows the user to type a string and then search for a word within that string. From there, the script would have to return all of the positions of that searched word. I have some example code here:

```
userinp = input("Please type a sentence: ")
list1[]
string1 = userinp.split()
for x in string1:
        list1.insert(x,string1[x])
search = input("Search for a word: ")
for x in range(len(string1)):
         if search in list1:
                   print("Word found at index:",x)
```

Please bare in mind this code may not work 100% as this was typed on a phone.

The actual task is to recall all of the positions of the words but after countless tries of trying, I cannot make it print the other indexes of the same word. For example, if the string was "Hello my name is Jack and my favourite food is apples" and I searched 'my', the program would have to return that the word was found at indexes 2 and 7.

As this was typed on a phone, the actual question may not have come out clear, if that is the case, please just comment saying so. Otherwise, any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
userinp = raw_input("Please type a sentence: ")
words = userinp.split(' ')
search = raw_input("Search for a word: ")
for idx, word in enumerate(words):
    if search == word:
        print("Word found at index:", idx)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly - I've never seemed to be able to get raw_input to work so just changed that to input.